# bs4 data scraping doesn't work on site as cloudflare is enabled

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Whilst trying to scrape https://quizlet.com/751002352/d2k2-die-kleidung-3-gegenteile-1-flash-cards/ for its header (among other things), instead of receiving `<h1>D2K2 die Kleidung 3 & Gegenteile 1</h1>`, I received `<h1>One more step…</h1>`. I tried find_all() in my code, and got this: `[<h1>One more step…</h1>, <h1 style="color:#bd2426;">Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page.</h1>]`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get(input('Link: ')).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
flashcard_title = soup.find_all('h1')
print(flashcard_title)
```

Using print(soup), turns out the site is protected by cloudflare and needs me to do a captcha (I think). Does anyone know how to get around this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered that the CAPTCHA is there to prevent *exactly* what you're trying to do? If there was a way to "*get around this*", what would be the point of a webmaster implementing it in the first place?

Comment: @esqew ? There is a way to get around it, therefore I will use it. And if there wasn’t, then this question would be unanswered and I’d move on. All things considered though, it seemed like there would be an answer to me considering how much data-scraping happens on the internet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. The page is loaded *dynamically* using JavaScript, so not all elements are available, `requests` doesn't support it.
2. You need to add the `user-agent` header, otherwise, the page thinks that your a bot and will block you.

```py
import requests
from html import unescape
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = "https://quizlet.com/751002352/d2k2-die-kleidung-3-gegenteile-1-flash-cards/"
HEADERS = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36"
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS).text, "html.parser")


print(unescape(soup.find("h1").text))
```

Prints:

```
D2K2 die Kleidung 3 & Gegenteile 1
```